# Null pointer Exception at ImageView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to do a DataBase Sqlite with display an image in home page.Then I am getting a null pointer exception at ImageView.

**StackTrace:**

```
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginregisterwithsqlite/com.example.loginregisterwithsqlite.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.example.loginregisterwithsqlite.Home.onCreate(Home.java:22)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-23 19:06:49.112: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  ... 11 more
```

**Home.java:**

```
package com.example.loginregisterwithsqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Home extends Activity{

    Button button1;
    ImageView imageView1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ --->22nd line

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                   imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

            }


        });

    }

}
```

**home.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D8D8D8" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Display an Image"/>  

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/android"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to display an image in the same screen.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

move

```
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

after

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

The views will be part of the activity view hierarchy after you call setContentView not before

Comment: worked fine.Thank you.will accept your answer after few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The child views can be generated only after the main view is ready.
Main view is set using the setContentView() function. Only after this you can create child view using findViewById()

So move the button1 and imageView1 creation after setContentView()

Like

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.home);

button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```